# Powershell: Characters in file path as index instead of file path as index?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a Powershell script to do an incremental differential backup of my computer, however I am having issues with how Powershell is interpreting file path variables.

```
$C_P86Files_Name=Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Test' -Recurse | foreach FullName
$B_P86Files_Name
$MovedFiles=0
$MovedBytes=0

#Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test.txt' -InputObject $C_P86Files_Name

Get-ChildItem -File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Test' -Recurse | foreach FullName

for ($i=0; $i -le ($C_P86Files_Name.Length-1); $i++)
{
    $B_P86Files_Name = $C_P86Files_Name[$i] -replace "^C", "B"

    Write-Host "Checking $($C_P86Files_Name[$i])"
    Write-Host "B drive directory: $($B_P86Files_Name[$i])"

    if(((ls $C_P86Files_Name[$i]).LastWriteTime -ne (ls $B_P86Files_Name[$i]).LastWriteTime) -or ((Test-Path $C_P86Files_Name[$i]) -and (!(Test-Path $B_P86Files_Name[$i]))))
    {
        Copy-Item $C_P86Files_Name[$i] -Destination $B_P86Files_Name[$i]
        $MovedFiles++;
        $MovedBytes+=(Get-Item $C_P86Files_Name[$i]).length

        Write-Host "Moved $($C_P86Files_Name[$i]) to $($B_P86Files_Name[$i])"
    }
}

Write-Host "Total data moved: $($MovedBytes)"
```

The output ends up showing that instead of iterating through `C:\Program Files (x86)\Test`, it tried iterating through each letter of that path as though it were a file, and then erroring out accordingly (e.g. it checks "C" and then checks ":" and then checks "\" and so forth).

I tried adding escaped quotes to the variables in the IF statement, but this did not effect anything.

The outfile does show a correct filepath, so it seems to get the correct information. What I don't understand is why the array `$C_P86Files_Name` appears to use each character from the path as an index in the array instead of each filer from Get-ChildItem as an index in the array?

Answer (score 0):

If you treat a (single) string as an array it will use an index as a char pointer, to prevent this use `@()` to force an array even with only 1 element.

Your usage of:

```
Get-ChildItem -File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Test' -Recurse | foreach FullName
```

Returns a string/an array of strings.

It would be much easier keeping them as an object you could iterate through (and still have access to it's properties)

```
$C_P86Files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Test' -Recurse
ForEach ($File in $C_P86Files){
    $B_FullName = $File.FullName -Replace '^C','B'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got past this issue. Seems as though another variable needs to be declared in order for the array to have one line per index instead of one character.

```
$Files=Get-ChildItem -File -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test" -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$C_P86Files_Name
$B_P86Files_Name
$MovedFiles=0
$MovedBytes=0
Out-File -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Test.txt" -InputObject $Files

'-----------------------------------------------------------------'

$C_P86Files_Name=$Files
$B_P86Files_Name=$Files

foreach($i in $C_P86Files_Name)
{
    $C_P86Files_Name[$i]
}

for ($i=0; $i -le ($C_P86Files_Name).Length; $i++)
{
    $B_P86Files_Name[$i]=$B_P86Files_Name[$i] -replace "^C", "B"

    Write-Host "C drive directory: $($C_P86Files_Name[$i])"
    Write-Host "B drive directory: $($B_P86Files_Name[$i])"

    if(((ls $C_P86Files_Name[$i]).LastWriteTime -ne (ls $B_P86Files_Name[$i]).LastWriteTime) -or ((Test-Path $C_P86Files_Name[$i]) -and (!(Test-Path $B_P86Files_Name[$i]))))
    {
        Copy-Item $C_P86Files_Name[$i] -Destination $B_P86Files_Name[$i]
        $MovedFiles++;
        $MovedBytes+=(Get-Item $C_P86Files_Name[$i]).length

        Write-Host "Moved $($C_P86Files_Name[$i]) to $($B_P86Files_Name[$i])"
    }
}

Write-Host "Total data moved: $($MovedBytes)"
```